# Replace HTML-encoded symbol (&trade;) in PHP string

Tags: php, character-encoding, substring

I'm trying to remove an encoded TM sign from a PHP string which is displayed as a a page title. The character displays as `&trade;` in the title, which is obviously ugly. Unfortunately none of the inbuilt encoding functions seem to deal with translation of very many encoded characters, and TM isn't one of them. What I want to do is replace '™' with '(tm)'.

Before I dig into substrings I wanted to see if anyone knew of a cleverer way to do this. I don't know the position the symbol appears in the string (it varies depending on the page title).

Any thoughts much appreciated!

Comment: Why is ™ ugly? Isn't that how it's supposed to show? Or is it showing as `&trade;`? In that case, that shouldn't be - you should show the HTML source code of the title tag

Comment: TM is fine - the problem is that it displays as &trade; in the title, whereas within the page it displays as TM (ie as expected)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
<title><?php print str_replace("&trade;", "™", $yourStr); ?></title>
```

Actually I don´t know is it the best way to do this, but at least it works.

Comment: Thanks, that does work and it very straightforward. Confusingly the $needle was '&amp;trade;' (because the CMS encoded the '&'. Not the most elegant solution I suspect, but I can't imagine it causes too much overhead. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you want to replace the '`&trade;`' with '(tm)' in a string in PHP. You can just use the `str_replace()` function for that.

It would look something like this

```
$titleString = "SOME TITLE - Trademark &trade; My Company";
$titleStringReplaced = str_replace("&trade;", "(tm)", $titleString);
```